# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() popup is not showing in TestFlight build

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, skstorereviewcontroller

I used SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() in my app but Rate app popup is not showing in test Flight build.

```
if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

In development or Add hoc build **Submit** button is disable which is perfectly fine. But in Test Flight build it not showing anything.

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Don't worry!

"This method has no effect when you call it in an app that you distribute using TestFlight"

[image]

see more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

Answer (score 6):

In production builds submitted to iTunes connect the rating display will only appear a maximum of 3 times in a single year, per a user, when requested.

In debug builds it will always appear.

In TestFlight builds it will never appear.

There is no way for you to control if it will appear, only to request it!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: this is not correct, their doc states you are responsible to choose when review request will appear: `You can determine when and where your app displays the prompt to request a review.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately you’re incorrect, as the document you posted states: Presenting your users with a request for an App Store review using SKStoreReviewController is a good way to get feedback on your app. However, be aware that the system displays the prompt to a user a maximum of three times within a 365-day period. You can determine when and where your app displays the prompt to request a review. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: You request a review when you want, and the system will decide if the prompt is shown or not! As the accepted answer states though, it will always show via debug builds for testing purposes 

Comment: yeah I agree that might not be clear from my comment, now your answer looks better after the edit, upvoted 